# Binding a string in App.vue,will not update after change

Tags: vue.js

I would like to show my logged in user or a logout link. To display them on every page place it in App.vue and change there also the routes. I grab the username from the store.

```
<template>
[...]
  <a v-if="!username" @click="$router.push({ name: 'Login' })">Login</a>
  <div v-if="username">{{ username }}</div>
  <a v-if="username" @click="logout">Logout</a>

  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </transition>
  </router-view>
[...]
</template>
<script>
[...]
   data() {
    return {
      username: this.$store.state.user.username,
    };
  },
[...]
</script>
```

After now updating $store.state.user.username in my login route, the user will not display in my App.vue. Do I have to re-render all or what am I missing? Any hint/help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`username` should be a computed property in order to be reactive and reflect state changes in your component :

```
computed:{
   username(){ return this.$store.state.user.username }
}
```

your conditional rendering should be like :

```
<template>
[...]
<a v-if="!username" @click="$router.push({ name: 'Login' })">Login</a>
<template v-else> 
 <div >{{ username }}</div>
  <a  @click="logout">Logout</a>

</template>
[...]
```

Comment: Quick and accurate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

u need a computed.

```js
computed: {
  userIsLoggedIn: function() {
    return this.$store.state.user.logdIn
  }
}
```

ur store state needs to have a state for loged in or out

after that u can setup ur login/logout button with a v-if when login is true or v-else when login is false